# Finding key corresponding to max value in c++ map

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, stl

Given a number say 'KEY' and map <int, int> myMap. I am trying to find a smallest key k (condition: k < KEY) in the map myMap such that it's value is maximum.

Example:

```
map <int, int> myMap = {{3,1}, {4,3}, {5,2}, {6,3}, {7,2}, {8,5}};
                             // ^^^
int KEY = 7;
```

Answer is 4, since for all the keys less than 7(KEY), the key 4 and key 6 has the maximum value of 3. 4 is the smallest key.

The map increases dynamically and there are several such queries with KEY.

I am trying to get the {k,v} pair in O(logN) time

I'm stuck after using lower_bound. Using lower bound gives me max 'k' such that k < KEY. In the example above I am able to get {7,2} for KEY=7. But struggling to get to {4,3} in logN time. Is there any data structure which can help me achieve this in logN time?

**Update:**

I am making sure to do the updates to the map in logarithmic time as well. Integers are not exceeding 10^5. Is it possible to use some other data structure and approach (in this case it looks like dynamic programming/binary search) to solve this in logarithmic time?

Comment: You could store, in each node, a key corresponding to maximum value among all preceding nodes. Or have a separate map of key to "key for max value among smaller keys". This would make answering this question fast - but of course it would make updating the map slow. This may or may not be a suitable tradeoff.

Comment: If you want to effectively search by some criteria, it has to be part of the key, not the value. Seems like `std::map<std::pair<int,int>,T>` (or a set) with a custom `operator<` would be better match.

Comment: This is impossible with this structure. Your condition gives you O(N) elements to consider. N elements with an unknown ordering.

Comment: How would you choose between `{4,3}` and `{6,3}`? They both have keys < 7 and the same value.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's Right. That would make updating the map slow. So we cannot use it. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I am wondering if I can use something else (one or more data structure) instead of map and get the queries and updates done in less than linear time.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated my question. I am looking for smallest key in such scenario.

Comment: Can you make any predictions on the value of the keys?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe KEY and {key and value} of the map will not exceed 10^5

Comment: You could reduce the complexity (but not by much) if you first took an `upper_bound` range (= O(logN)) and then searched that sub-range for the max (= O(N'), where N' is the new size minus 1). Would that help?

Comment: A `boost::multiindex` container might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. You maintain a secondary map, a subset of your primary one. Specifically, this secondary map would contain `{k, v}` if and only if all smaller keys in the primary map correspond to smaller values.

For your example of `{3,1}, {4,3}, {5,2}, {6,3}, {7,2}, {8,5}`, this secondary map would be `{3,1}, {4,3}, {8,5}`. Observe how values are monotonously increasing along with keys.

It should be obvious how to use this map to answer the question - simply look up the key with `lower_bound`. In the example, for the key of 7, the lookup will find 4, the correct answer.

Now, how to maintain this map. When you insert `{k, v}` into the primary map, look up `k` in the secondary map using `lower_bound`. There are two possibilities:

- There exists a smaller key with equal or larger value. Do nothing, the secondary map doesn't need to be updated.
- There doesn't exist a smaller key, or the smaller key corresponds to a smaller value. Then

  - Insert `{k, v}` into the secondary map
  - Walk keys sequentially, starting from `k` until you encounter the key `k'` with a larger value, or reach the end. Erase the range between `k` and `k'` (exclusive of both), or from `k` (exclusive) to the end.

On the surface, this last step looks linear - but in fact it's amortized constant. Over `N` insertions, this step would have to walk `2*N` elements at most (e.g. first `N-1` steps inserting one element each, and the last step removing them all and inserting one).

Comment: Looks like this works. Thanks for pointing out the amortized constant part.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any data structure which can help me achieve this in logN time?

Not really unless you are able to combine those values in a meaningful fashion. All (almost) log N algorithms relies on a divide and conquer approach.

You have essentially two unrelated sequences. The key mapped by tree allows you to do log N stuff but then you need another search on an unstructured sequence this is O(N).

So for this to be done on O(log N) you need to somehow combine the key and the value or go the route comment @Igor suggested which is essentially a map of maps.

Of course tweaking implementation might bring benefits but not O(N) -> O(log N) type benefits.